# Extract only title from hyperlink in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have pandas column with hyperlinks and I want to extract only the name of the domain, excluding ".com", "http//", "www."

The following code works for most of my cases but there is one where it does not return the desired string:

```
docs['link_title'] = docs['hyperlink'].str.extract(r'(?<=\.)(.*?)(?=\.)')
```

Below are examples of hyperlinks and the results:

http://www.traveldailymedia.com/240881/qantas-launches-uk-agent-incentive/
-> "traveldailymedia"

https://www.instagram.com/p/BKDJcO-htRs/    -> "instagram"

But this is an example where I don't get the title of the domain:

http://dtinews.vn/en/news/018/46981/vietnam-to-buy-40-airbus-planes.html
-> "vn/en/news/018/46981/vietnam-to-buy-40-airbus-planes"

Because there is no leading dot (".") it does not get the name which is "dtinews".

I would appreciate help with the regex here or some alternative to my approach.

Comment: Looks like you will still have issues with `yy.xxx.co.uk` like domains.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't bother trying to figure out such a common problem on my own but instead look for some ready-made solution like [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tldextract`](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/):

```py
import tldextract
import pandas as pd
docs = pd.DataFrame({'hyperlink':["http://www.traveldailymedia.com/240881/qantas-launches-uk-agent-incentive/","https://www.instagram.com/p/BKDJcO-htRs/","http://dtinews.vn/en/news/018/46981/vietnam-to-buy-40-airbus-planes.html"]})
docs['link_title'] = docs['hyperlink'].apply(lambda x: tldextract.extract(x).domain)
```

Output:

```
>>> docs['link_title']
0    traveldailymedia
1           instagram
2             dtinews
```

Comment: That's great! Just what I needed. Thanks